Multi covariates setting and scaling problem using own data in Darts
I imported the data and converted it into time series, set the target and covariates, divided the training set, test set, and validation set, and normalized them separately. It is not clear to me how to divide the training set, test set, and validation set and scaling them after stacking or concatenating more than two covariates.
If I set:
past_covariates = concatenate([A, B, C, D], axis=1)
stacked_covariates = past_covariates1.stack([past_covariates2, past_covariates3, ..., past_covariatesN])
how to divide and scale past covariates?
Below is my code, the division and standardization of training sets, test sets and validation sets also seem troublesome, please give me some suggestions.
train_ratio = 0.8
val_ratio = 0.1
test_ratio = 0.1

file_path = 'D:/xxx.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df.set_index('Timestamp', inplace=True)

# TODO: multivariate time series
# target_column_names = ['algal', 'chlorophyll']
target_column_names = ['chlorophyll']
covariate_columns_names = ['TEM', 'PH', 'DO', 'conductivity', 'turbidity', 'PV', 'AN', 'TP', 'TN']

target_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df, value_cols=target_column_names, freq='H')
covariate_series = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df, value_cols=covariate_columns_names, freq='H')

# time series split
train_target, temp_target = target_series.split_before(train_ratio)
val_target, test_target = temp_target.split_before(val_ratio / (1 - train_ratio))
train_covariates, temp_covariates = covariate_series.split_before(train_ratio)
val_covariates, test_covariates = temp_covariates.split_before(val_ratio / (1 - train_ratio))

# time series scaling
scaler_target = Scaler()
scaler_covariates = Scaler()

target_scaled = scaler_target.fit_transform(target_series)

train_target_scaled = scaler_target.fit_transform(train_target)
val_target_scaled = scaler_target.transform(val_target)
model_target_scaled = concatenate([train_target_scaled, val_target_scaled])
test_target_scaled = scaler_target.transform(test_target)

train_covariates_scaled = scaler_covariates.fit_transform(train_covariates)
val_covariates_scaled = scaler_covariates.transform(val_covariates)
model_covariates_scaled = concatenate([train_covariates_scaled, val_covariates_scaled])
test_covariates_scaled = scaler_covariates.transform(test_covariates)
all_covariates_scaled = concatenate([model_covariates_scaled, test_covariates_scaled])

# plot
train_target_scaled.plot(label="training")
val_target_scaled.plot(label="validation")
test_target_scaled.plot(label="test")
plt.show()

